How to get coefficient values for all treatments in a zero-intercept lm model
(edited to include two instead of one categorical variable)
I have a hypothetical dataset with two categorical variables, 4 mutually exclusive treatments and 5 mutually exclusive groups, and a continuous variable, as well as a response variable. Each treatment is coded as a dummy variable and is either 0 or 1.
I am trying to fit a linear regression model with an intercept fixed at zero (y ~ 0 + treat1 + treat2 + treat3 + treat4 + group1 + group2 + group3 + group4 + group5 + contvar) using the lm() function in R. I want to get coefficient estimates for all four treatments, all five groups, as well as the continuous variable.
Here's a reproducible example of my issue:
set.seed(123) # added

# Sample size
n <- 100

# Generate predictors, treatments 1 - 4 that are mutually exclusive, and a continuous variable
data <- data.frame(
  treat1 = c(rep(1, 25), rep(0, 75)),
  treat2 = c(rep(0, 25), rep(1, 25), rep(0, 50)),
  treat3 = c(rep(0, 50), rep(1, 25), rep(0, 25)),
  treat4 = c(rep(0, 75), rep(1, 25)), # edit
  group1 = rep(c(rep(1, 5), rep(0, 20)), 4),
  group2 = rep(c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5), rep(0, 15)), 4),
  group3 = rep(c(rep(0, 10), rep(1, 5), rep(0, 10)), 4),
  group4 = rep(c(rep(0, 15), rep(1, 5), rep(0, 5)), 4),
  group5 = rep(c(rep(0, 20), rep(1, 5)), 4),
  contvar = sample(0:100, n)/100
)

# Define means for each treatment
mean1 <- rnorm(100, -0.5, 0.1) ; mean2 <- rnorm(100, -0.2, 0.1) ; mean3 <- rnorm(100, 0.2, 0.1) ; mean4 <- rnorm(100, 0.5, 0.1)

# Define means for each group
meangr1 <- rnorm(100, -1, 0.2) ; meangr2 <- rnorm(100, -0.1, 0.1) ; meangr3 <- rnorm(100, 0, 0.1) ; meangr4 <- rnorm(100, 0.1, 0.1) ; meangr5 <- rnorm(100, 1, 0.2)

# Generate response variable y based on the treatment means, group means and the value of the continuous variable
data$y <- mean1 * data$treat1 + mean2 * data$treat2 + mean3 * data$treat3 + mean4 * data$treat4
data$y <- data$y * data$contvar
data$y <- data$y + meangr1 * data$group1 + meangr2 * data$group2 + meangr3 * data$group3 + meangr4 * data$group4 + meangr5 * data$group5

# Fit a no-intercept model
model0 <- lm(y ~ 0 + treat1 + treat2 + treat3 + treat4 + 
               group1 + group2 + group3 + group4 + group5 +
               contvar, data = data)

# Summarize the no-intercept model
summary(model0)

The generated outcome reads:
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + treat1 + treat2 + treat3 + treat4 + group1 + 
    group2 + group3 + group4 + group5 + contvar, data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.54069 -0.11705 -0.00558  0.11709  0.56169 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
treat1   0.67980    0.07089   9.590 1.84e-15 ***
treat2   0.96646    0.06949  13.908  < 2e-16 ***
treat3   1.14318    0.07113  16.071  < 2e-16 ***
treat4   1.22735    0.06751  18.180  < 2e-16 ***
group1  -2.01289    0.06154 -32.710  < 2e-16 ***
group2  -1.11811    0.06144 -18.200  < 2e-16 ***
group3  -1.07177    0.06311 -16.983  < 2e-16 ***
group4  -0.89593    0.06313 -14.193  < 2e-16 ***
group5        NA         NA      NA       NA    
contvar -0.01132    0.06987  -0.162    0.872    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1938 on 91 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9301,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9232 
F-statistic: 134.6 on 9 and 91 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

There is a coefficient for all treatments but not for all groups. Why is this the case? I understand that getting coefficient estimates for all treatments and all groups would not work with a random intercept model, where one category from each would be selected as reference, but with a zero-intercept model I expected it would work.
Just to illustrate, this is what happens if I fit the model with a random intercept:
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ treat1 + treat2 + treat3 + treat4 + group1 + 
    group2 + group3 + group4 + group5 + contvar, data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.54069 -0.11705 -0.00558  0.11709  0.56169 

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.22735    0.06751  18.180  < 2e-16 ***
treat1      -0.54755    0.05509  -9.940 3.41e-16 ***
treat2      -0.26089    0.05491  -4.751 7.51e-06 ***
treat3      -0.08417    0.05513  -1.527    0.130    
treat4            NA         NA      NA       NA    
group1      -2.01289    0.06154 -32.710  < 2e-16 ***
group2      -1.11811    0.06144 -18.200  < 2e-16 ***
group3      -1.07177    0.06311 -16.983  < 2e-16 ***
group4      -0.89593    0.06313 -14.193  < 2e-16 ***
group5            NA         NA      NA       NA    
contvar     -0.01132    0.06987  -0.162    0.872    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1938 on 91 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9301,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9239 
F-statistic: 151.3 on 8 and 91 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

This happens if I fit a linear model manually, however, by building a no-intercept linear model function, and then minimising the residual sum of squares with optim. Then I do get coefficients for all treatments and for the continuous variable:
lm_manual <- function(b){
  b1 <- b[1];  b2 <- b[2];  b3 <- b[3];  b4 <- b[4]; 
  bgr1 <- b[5];  bgr2 <- b[6];  bgr3 <- b[7];  bgr4 <- b[8]; bgr5 <- b[9]; 
  bcont <- b[10]
  y <- 0 + b1*data$treat1 + b2*data$treat2 + b3*data$treat3 + b4*data$treat4 + bcont*data$contvar
  SSR <- sum((y - data$y)^2)
}

out <- optim(par = c(-0.5, -0.2, 0.2, 0.5, -1, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 1, 0.01), fn = lm_manual)
(out$par) # coefficients for treatment 1 - 4, group 1 - 5 and the continuous variable

This reads: -0.42869647 -0.13663451  0.03372066  0.13213677 -1.64310116  0.61429850  0.51688837 -0.10915319  1.14837076  0.15682632. These estimates were what I expected to get when fitting the lm zero-intercept model. In the lm zero-intercept model both the values of the coefficients, and the NA for group5 were unexpected.
How can I get such coefficient estimates using lm? Or if that is not possible: why would this only work when fitting the model "manually" and not when fitting with lm?

When using random data, please use set.seed() so we can recreate the same data as you for testing. your treat1 and treat4 variables seem to be identical. They are either both true or both false. That would lead to an unidentifiable model.

all(data$treat1 == data$treat4) is TRUE, so that's why treat4 is not estimated. To see why you get treat1FALSE included, just start with the model that only includes treat1, what would it mean if you would only get a treat1TRUE parameter without an intercept? By the way, that fit with the intercept, is not a random intercept.

To get the model you want, it's easier to not use dummy variables. Just have a single "treatment" variable, with 4 levels, then fit y ~ 0 + treatment + contvar.

After edits your model is still underspecified. Are you trying to have just one treatment active at a time? Because right now you have T1+T4, T2+T4, T3+T4, and then no treatment. There's no way to estimate just the effect of T4. If you need help understanding the requirements for linear modeling, you should probably seek help at [stats.se] instead. This has less to do with programming than statistics.

The treatments should indeed be mutually exclusive, and one should always be active. That should be right in the example now. Given those mutually exclusive treatments, then can I get just the effect of T4? And can I get that too when there are two categorical variables (treatment and group) where there is always one group active and one treatment active? My question is about in the comparison between my "manual" lm function and the original lm function.
